# Read String From Text file and use it as a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file which contains two lines. They both contains the hours in this format.

> 14,0,0
>
> 15,0,0

I'm reading this text file in C# and getting both lines into two different strings:

```
         if (File.Exists(txtFile))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFile);
                startHour = lines[0];
                endHour = lines[1];
            }
```

So startHour = 14,0,0 and endHour = 15,0,0

```
            TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            
            if (now <= end && now >= start)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("between the hour");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dont match");
            }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to replace the hard coded hours from start and end TimeSpan with the values from Text File

```
            TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
```

When I tried this:

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(startHour);
```

I get an error:

> cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'long'

I tried to use TimeSpan.Parse(startHour) but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
var startLine = lines[0].Split(',');
var endLine = lines[1].Split(',');

var startHour = int.Parse(startLine[0]);
var startMin = int.Parse(startLine[1]);
var startSec = int.Parse(startLine[2]);

var endHour = int.Parse(endLine[0]);
var endMin = int.Parse(endLine[1]);
var endSec = int.Parse(endLine[2]);

TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(startHour, startMin , startSec);
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(endHour, endMin, endSec);
```

Answer (score 1):

TimeSpan has got 4 Overload Method and None of them States that If you pass a String to its Consructor,it will parse and yield you Time Span Object.So the Error is because

```
startHour = lines[0];
```

gets mapped to long Constructor of TimeSpan.

And to Resolve this you must use something like this

```
var SplitTime = lines[0].Split(',');

TimeSpan sample = new TimeSpan(SplitTime[0], SplitTime[1], SplitTime[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) can handle this:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(lines[0], "h','m','s", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the `TimeSpan.ParseExact` method.